# How to parse command tree in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line-interface, yacc, lex

I'm writing a console application on C++ and I need to get user shell-like command system to configure options in applications. For example, user could write something like this:

**register** *name*

**connection** **open** *[ telnet | ssh ]*

**connection** **switch** *telnet*

**send** *text*

**connection**  **switch** *ssh*

**send** *text*

*...and so on...*

---

So, obvious we have some command tree, in above example we have:

```
--register
|
--connetion
|         |--open
|         |--switch
|
--send
```

Each command can have different amount of parameters.

---

**QUESTION:**

- How to parse such command tree?

Now I parse it by regular expressions, but this solution is really ugly. I have read about YACC and LEX, but I'm not sure that this is a really good idea to use it.

Is there some widely-used approach to parse command tree? I'm not cool in lexical analysis theory, so I would appreciate if you will answer not in academic manner.

Comment: Suggestion: use a state machine that has a (state, char) -> (state, optional<std::function<void()>> ) transition function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html) is a good resource with a couple options if you can use the GNU C Library.

In the end you are going to want to switch each arg and you may need to keep track of some state for your nested commands.

Using your example arg tree:

```
switch (arg)
{
    case "register":
    {
        register = 1;
        break;
    }
    case "connection":
    {
        connection = 1;
        break;
    }
    case "open":
    {
        if (previousCommand == "connection")
            connectionOpen = 1;
        else
            //error
        break;
    }
    case "switch":
    {
        if (previousCommand == "connection")
            connectionSwitch = 1;
        else
            //error
        break;
    }
    case "send":
    {
        send = 1;
        break;
    }
    previousCommand = arg;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use strings for `case` statements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it I think it's not so good idea to use states for each command. Especially when command tree is pretty big.

Comment: @Galik, of course we can't. But it's not so big problem to convert strings to unique enum values.